# Python ctypes keybd_event simulate ctrl+alt+delete

Tags: python, winapi, keyboard-shortcuts, ctypes

I'm trying to simulate ctrl+alt+del with keybd_event but it doesn't do anything, stuff like ctrl+esc or alt+tab do work yet ctrl+alt+del won't work.

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x11, 0, 0, 0) #CTRL is down
ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x12, 0, 0, 0) #ALT is down
ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x2E, 0, 0, 0) #DEL is down
ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x2E, 0, 0x0002, 0) #DEL is up
ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x12, 0, 0x0002, 0) #ALT is up
ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x11, 0, 0x0002, 0) #CTRL is up
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd> is a special key sequence, known as the [secure attention sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_attention_key) that, for security reasons, cannot be faked using `keybd_input` or `SendInput`.

You will need to use the [`SendSAS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd979761.aspx) API call to simulate the SAS. Do read the documentation carefully do make sure that you adhere to the stringent requirements of this function.

Comment: Is creating a service in session 0 the best way to go about this for a Python script that's using ctypes? I think a program can enable this for a service by setting the system policy `SoftwareSASGeneration` to 1 or 3. To clarify the docs, for Vista support sas.dll is distributed in the Windows 7 SDK, in the Redist folder. Per License\\Redist.txt, it's ok to distribute this binary.

Comment: @eryksun Yeah, As I read it you can redist the DLL on Vista. A service will get it done, but it seems pretty heavy. There may be other reasons to prefer not to impose a service on the user. If it's a desktop app, then there are a few more hoops to jump through. Not easy to do with Python/ctypes given that the process that executes the code is typically python.exe. I'd go for a small executable to do the work, built with C++ using the SDK.

Comment: If XP support is desired, is it back to requiring a service? I think you need to be `SYSTEM` to send the ctrl+alt+del hotkey to the `Winlogon` desktop. I don't have an XP box to test this.

Comment: @eryksun It's kind of mirky at that point. MS only supplied the saslib code on demand. And the e-mail address they provided to make the request has been ignored for years. I think you are looking at reversing it yourself, or using something like http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/tag/saslibex/  Good places to look are open source VNC programs because they very commonly need to send SAS

Comment: If my application is set as uiAccess=false and is not a service is it still possible to send a secure attn request @DavidHeffernan ?

Answer (score 1):

That's a Windows security mechanism. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd> is special. At least one justification is the "Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd> for login prompt" thing where by pressing it you make sure Windows is really asking for your password and not just some program masquerading as a Windows prompt.